# Wordpress: insert same code with different parameters into multiple pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm still a Wordpress newbie, so (hopefully) this is an entirely dumb question.

I need to insert the same embed code (something like this, it's just copied from a visualisation on Tableau Public) (...):

```
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1591173837909' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='http:&#47;&#47;issarfwd.cenia.cz&#47;jihocesky-kraj&#47;ovzdusi&#47;'><img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Kr&#47;Kraje-Ovzdu&#47;Emisnsituace&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='path' value='views&#47;Kraje-Ovzdu&#47;Emisnsituace?:embed=y&amp;:toolbar=yes&amp;:embed_code_version=3&amp;Parameters.Kraj=Jiho%C4%8Desk%C3%BD%20kraj&amp;:loadOrderID=0&amp;:display_count=y?:embed%3Dy' /> <param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Kr&#47;Kraje-Ovzdu&#47;Emisnsituace&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='filter' value='Parameters.Kraj=Jiho%C4%8Desk%C3%BD%20kraj' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1591173837909');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    vizElement.style.width='1024px';vizElement.style.height='850px';                    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>
```

into several different Wordpress pages within one site. Each time, the embed code should have a different parameter. I chose the parameter to be the subtitle of the page and came up with this code (it works):

````
if (is_page()) {
$subtitle = apply_filters( 'plugins/wp_subtitle/get_subtitle', '', array(
   ) );
   if ((strpos($subtitle , 'kraj') == false) && (strpos($subtitle , 'Praha') == false) && (strpos($subtitle , 'Vysočina') == false)) {$subtitle = "Všechny kraje";};
 echo
"<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1591084101025' style='position: relative'><noscript>
<a href='#'><img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Kr&#47;Kraje-Ovzdu&#47;Emisnsituace&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' />
</a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> 
<param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='path' value='views&#47;Kraje-Ovzdu&#47;Emisnsituace?:embed=y&amp;:display_count=y' />
<param name='filter' value='Parameters.Kraj="  . $query->post->post_title . $subtitle . "'>
 <param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Kr&#47;Kraje-Ovzdu&#47;Emisnsituace&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1591084101025');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                 
   vizElement.style.width='1024px';vizElement.style.height='850px';                    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>";}?> ```
````

The embed code (=in quotes above) is messy, so just to highlight the single thing I changed inside it:

`<param name='filter' value='Parameters.Kraj="  . $query->post->post_title . $subtitle . "'>`

I would like to insert something like the above into a page template, so that I don't have to insert the slightly changed code into every page individually.

The question is: where should I load the embed code from? If it changes, I would like people to be able to edit it from the admin area. This should be a single place: a user pastes it in there → it gets read by the page template → the code gets changed in any page that has this template. Could this maybe be done from a page that won't be made public? Any other tips?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a shortcode with parameters:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API.

Comment: Do you have ACF fields installed? You could use an options page field on there and then use the shortcode to look at what value is in there when it pulls it in. Happy to provide examples, but need to know if you can/already installed ACF

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester it ocurred to me to use shortcodes, but then someone with php knowledge would need to edit the embed code, isn't that correct? I need this part to be very user friendly, though. 
I don't have ACF fields installed and I don't yet entirely see where you are going with this, but I'll definitely try to look at that. Meanwhile, if you'd like to elaborate a bit, it would be very appreciated :)

Comment: ACF options page is where you would put a field for the editable bits of the embed code, from there you would have a shortcode that you create that gets the field from the ACF options page (described in @FloJDM answer) and use that to create the output for the full embed. Does that make more sense? -- this whole method would mean any old non developer could edit the editable parts of embed code whilst the shortcode looks after all the tricky parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a option page with ACF for WP :

```
add_action('acf/init', 'register_my_options_pages');

function register_my_options_pages() {

    if( !function_exists('acf_add_options_page') )
        return;

    $option_page = acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => __('Settings page'),
        'menu_title'    => __('Settings page'),
        'menu_slug'     => 'my-general-settings',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'      => false
    ));
}
```

Follow this link to find a step by step usage :
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to ACF, that was exactly what I needed!